# For Loop Troubles

Tags: python

I am brand new to Python and I am trying to figure out how to create a for loop. Below is what I tried, and I got the error "can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'Symbol'" Any help would be great!

```
k=1 
c=[0,5,10,20,30] 
for i in c: integrate(sp.cos(k*x+c*x), (x, -2, 2))
```

Comment: what is `x` here?

Comment: What is `x`? I do not see the value assigned in code. Also I think you want to do `i*x` instead of `c*x`

Comment: The intepreter politely says that the c*x  operation has no meaning.

Answer (score 0):

First of all x is not defined and this will cause an error
And you should write the for loop like this
You should not use i for the loop in this case because i stands for index but in this case i would be an element of the list.

```
for elm in your_list:
    #code
    #more code
```

But most of the time if you use a for loop you want the index of the element and you should write it like this

```
for i in range(0, len(your_list)):
    print(your_list[i])
```

This would print out every element of the list